# Inquiry about Perl Regexes

Tags: regex, perl

This question is related to one I asked yesterday. I'm new to Perl and am still getting the hang of things*. In the code, I am trying to replace right single quotation marks with apostrophes. However, I do not want to replace the right single quotation on singly quoted words. An example being:

```
He said the movie was 'magnificent.'
```

Here's the code I'm currently working with:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# Subroutine prototype
sub problem_character();

my $previousPosition=0;
my $currentPosition=0;

#Locates problematic apostrophes and replaces them with properly encoded apostrophes
sub problem_character(){
    while($_[0]=~m/\x{2019}/g){
        $currentPosition=pos($_[0]);
        pos($_[0])=$previousPosition;
        unless(....){
            $_[0]=~s/\x{2019}/\x{0027}/g;
        }
        $previousPosition=$currentPosition;
    }
}
```

First off, I'm not sure what I would put in the unless check. I want to be able to check if the matched right single quote is part of a singly quoted word. Also, in the Perl documentation, it was the pos function the offset where the last `m//q` search left off. Does the replacement search also fall under this category? Finally, is there a simpler way of writing this type of code? Thanks.

*Does anyone know of a good book I could pick up that explains Peril in detail? I found the online resources to be quite confusing.

Comment: I used Perl Docs, StackOverflow, and just this one tutorial: http://qntm.org/files/perl/perl.html and I think I learned pretty quickly with that.

Comment: Check out all the Perl books published by O'Reilly & Associates. _Programming Perl_ is the one I learned from 20 years ago.

Comment: Pro tip: don't use subroutine prototypes -- they don't do what you're used to them doing in other languages, and are rarely useful. Abandon any online resources that encourage you to use prototypes in Perl.

Comment: In addition to the books mentioned, [Modern Perl](http://onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/) is pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

You posted you have the following:

```
He said the movie was 'magnificent.'
```

But you said you were trying to replace `’` which aren't present in that string. Do you actually have the following?

```
He said the movie was ‘magnificent.’
```

If so, the simple solution would be to replace all `’` that aren't matched by a preceding `‘`. It's a bit tricky to implement, though.

```
s{
    \G
    (?: [^\x{2018}\x{2019}]++
    |   \x{2018} [^\x{2018}\x{2019}]*+ \x{2019}?+
    )*+
    \K
    \x{2019}
}{'}xg;
```

---

Simpler (but a little less efficient) implementation:

```
$_ = reverse($_);
s/\x{2019}(?![^\x{2018}\x{2019}]*\x{2018})/'/g;
$_ = reverse($_);
```

---

By the way, you can actually use the characters `‘` and `’` in the regex pattern if you want. Just make sure to encode your file using UTF-8 and tell Perl you did that using `use utf8;`

```
use utf8;  # Source code is encoded using UTF-8.

$_ = reverse($_);
s/’(?![^‘’]*‘)/'/g;
$_ = reverse($_);
```

Comment: @user3639182 [if an answer helps you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) then consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/230282)